# Displaying the file in Laravel Expense Manager

Tags: php, laravel, upload

How do I display the file or images in my project. I have this code in uploading the file.

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $expense = new expenses;
    $expense->title = Input::get('name');
        if (Input::hasFile('image')){
            $expense=Input::expense('image');
            $expense->move(public_path(). '/', $file->getClientOriginalName());

            $expense->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        }

    $expenses->save();
    return 'data save in the database';
}
```

This is my code in Create blade..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        {!! Form::label('image', 'Photo:') !!}
            <form action="upload" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" multiple><br />
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                @if($errors->has('image'))
                    <p class="help-block">
                        {{ $errors->first('image') }}
                    </p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
```

In my index blade, showing the file I uploaded..

```
<tbody>
    @if (count($expenses) > 0)
         @foreach ($expenses as $expense)
             <td><img src="/image/{{ $expense }}" style="width:150px; height:150px;"></td>
         @endforeach
</tbody>
```

How do I display my file or images in my table, what code do I need to complete it. This code above I just follow the tutorials given to me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to close off your form:

```
<form action="..">
    ...
</form>
```

Secondly, you are requesting an input you don't have here:

```
$expense->title = Input::get('name');
```

Thirdly, you are trying to save a variable that doesn't exist:

```
$expenses->save();
```

should it be:

```
$expense->save()?
```

there is still another error where you are calling:

```
<td><img src="/image/{{ $expense }}"
```

hope this helps for now